# Passing scope to AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a specific scenario for a AngularJS directive:

- Normally the directive should inherit the default scope
- But for some specific scenarios I'd like to replace all values in `$scope.myValues` with `myValues` (object loaded from a web-service)

I cannot change in this scenario the main-scope because this is owned by another application (more or less a plugin-mechanism).

Thanks & Regards
Stefan

Comment: Can't you simply set your `$scope.myValues = MyDirective.getNewValues()` within your $http web service success?

Comment: Can you post some example code showing what have you tried?

Comment: Please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing the answer into the question.

Comment: @Wex: OK, yes, you are right, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think I have found the solution:

***Sample Html:***

```
<wi-view data-layout="{{passLayout}}"></wi-view>
<hr />
Original property: {{layout.property1}}
```

***Sample Controller:***

```
app.controller('wiController', function($scope) {

    // Simulating the original scope values
    $scope.layout = {};
    $scope.layout.property1 = 'Original Value';

    // New scope values, just here for binding it to the controller
    var passLayout = {};
    passLayout.property1 = 'Value Overwritten';
    passLayout.property2 = 'Another Property';
    $scope.passLayout = passLayout;

});
```

***Sample Directive:***

```
app.directive('wiView', function () {
var linkFunction = function(scope, elems, attrs) {

    if (attrs.layout !== undefined) {
        scope.layout = angular.fromJson(attrs.layout);
    }
};

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: true,
    priority: 0,
    link: linkFunction,
    template: '<div>Hello, {{layout.property1}}!</div>'
};
```

});